# There are two phases in sequence - correct?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

I know that "in sequence" means "one by one" or "one after another". I want to express that there are two phases (A and B) and that they are exactly in this order and do not overlap.
Would this be correct?

> In this game, there are two phases in sequence: A and B.

Is that correct?

Comment: I submit that *phase* already implies "no overlap" all by itself, especially in the context of gaming. "The game has two phases, A and B" is perfectly sufficient. The order as well is more than sufficiently implied.

Comment: _Phase_ is a word that can be used precisely in context, but is not in general a very clear word. One way people use the word is in the phrase _phase of the moon_, and everybody knows this is a very slow gradual process, with considerable overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more common approach would be to say

> In this game, there are two *sequential* phases: A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you need is 'discrete', which means 'individually separate and distinct' (Oxford Dictionary of English). 'Two discrete phases' would indicate there was no overlap between them. 'Discrete' is not to be confused with 'discreet' which means 'careful and prudent in one's speech and actions'.